# Is it possible to edit alarms?

Tags: ios, alarmmanager

i am trying to edit the alarm that user set on iphone using objective -C code? is it possible?

Or can i create a alarm in my application to remind user when a time has reach? :) Cant find any solution for the past days researching.. thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't edit the user's alarms, but applications can schedule local notifications using the [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.